# Trigger button click after view got loaded

Tags: c#, jquery, model-view-controller

In my old MVC application, I have a login button once the application main page got loaded I have to explicitly click on login to get into the application. Now I would like to trigger the login_btn click event after my view got loaded via code.

In Jquery called the login_btn trigger event in document.ready function, and in controller I used viewBag option. Which is the best way to achieve

In jquery,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#login_btn').trigger('click');
});
```

Its getting called when the page get refreshed.

In controller viewBag

```
public IActionResult Index(string info)
{
    loginModel myModel = new loginModel();
    test(); //tried
    return View(myModel);
}

public void test()
{
    ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction = "login()";
}
```

gives error login not defined, because before loading the model I am calling the test()

Provide me some info on how to trigger the login automatically after the view page got loaded.

Comment: Can you show how is you form ?

Comment: added the form  `@if (ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction != null)
{
    <script type="text/javascript">             @Html.Raw(ViewBag.JavaScriptFunction)
    </script>
}`

Comment: Where is the login function?

Comment: Its just a normal jquery function which i would like to call..As it has some senstitive info i cant share.

Answer (score 0):

Modifying my original answer, the solution using a flag to control the auto-login would be:

```
    if( alreadyLoggedFlag === false ) { 
        alreadyLoggedFlag = true; 
        $('#login_btn').trigger('click'); 
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but its triggered when the page is refreshed or loaded, so personally I felt its a drawback, bcoz login button should be called only once in the application.

Comment: then use a global flag

if( alreadyLoggedFlag === false ) {
   alreadyLoggedFlag = true;
   $('#login_btn').trigger('click');
}

Comment: Finally I have added the ``@section scripts {
    <script type="text/javascript">
        if ($("#CAMNamespaceLocal").text() !== "") { $('#login_btn').trigger('click'); }
    </script>}`` in Index.cshtml. It worked as expected. Is this approach ok??

Comment: Is a good approach, you could also use a class in #login_btn to check if it should be clicked. Perhaps you hide your button, so you can check it as a flag. That way you rely on the functionality in the same element instead of external ones.